# new instance of object creation for updating a record

Tags: apex, after-trigger, code, business-logic

Requirement-I have custom object request__C where i am storing sourceAccount ID and TargetAccountID.
My requirement is to update the field in request object with max contact in any of the account.
suppost 
SourceAccount having 3 contacts
targetAccount having 7 contacts then field needs to be updated with 7 in request object.
Below is my code

```
public class RequestController {

public static void UpdateAccountOnRequest(List<Request__c> request){
    Set<id> sourceId = new set<id>();
    set<id> targetId = new set<id>();
    for(Request__c mr:request) {
        sourceId.add(mr.Sourceaccount__c);
        sourceId.add(mr.TargetAccount__c);    
    }
    List<account> accList =new list<account>([select id,(select id from contacts) from account where id in:sourceId]);
    map<id,Integer> conMap = new map<id,integer>();
    for(account acc:accList) {
        integer numbers = acc.contacts.size();
        conMap.put(acc.id, numbers);
    }
    list<Request__c> mrUpdate = new list<Request__c>();
    system.debug('conMap-->'+conMap);
    for(Request__c mr:request){
        integer scount = conMap.get(mr.Sourceaccount__c);
        integer Tcount = conMap.get(mr.TargetAccount__c);
        Request__c mrs =  new Request__c();
        mrs.id = mr.id;
        if(scount>Tcount) {

            mrs.Maximum_Contact_on_Account__c = string.valueOf(conMap.get(mr.Sourceaccount__c));
        }
        else {
            mrs.Maximum_Contact_on_Account__c = string.valueOf(conMap.get(mr.TargetAccount__c));
        }
        mrUpdate.add(mrs);
    }
    update mrUpdate;
}
```

i am confused on this lines

```
            Request__c mrs =  new Request__c();
            mrs.id = mr.id;
```

Weather i have written it correctly.My code is working fine but just wanted to know if any issue on large volume of date bcause of above lines like instance creation and id assignemnt.

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that this line is correct `for(Merge_Request__c mr:request){`. As I see it,`request` is a list of type `Request__c` not `Merge_Request__c`.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Hi, it won't have a negative impact. Actually I like to do that when you do not trust the source of the "request" because you make sure that you don't update anything you don't want to. I'll let you know that you could use `Request__c mrs = new Request__c(Id = mr.Id);`(single line) and that your set targetId is unused. You could also use `Math.max` instead of your if(scount>Tcount). But its up to you ;). What is really important is that the `update mrUpdate;`is outside any loop (so, good).